# Client certificates access key (encrypted)

Tags: encryption, key, certificate

I have a client certificate files (.perm,.csr,.pfx,.key) and these files contain hex code
The below code snippet takes a cipherText and performs some validation. This is a servlet and the cipherText is passed as a request paramter. I looked into cert files and provided all the hex code available in those files as input but nothing seem to work.

Looking at the way its decoded can anyone tell what kind of input its expecting from the certificate files:

```
validate(cipherText)
 private static final byte[] desKeyData = {
        (byte)0xA2, (byte)0x15, (byte)0x37, (byte)0x07, (byte)0xCB, (byte)0x62, 
        (byte)0xC1, (byte)0xD3, (byte)0xF8, (byte)0xF1, (byte)0x97, (byte)0xDF,
        (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x13, (byte)0x4F, (byte)0x79, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x67, 
        (byte)0x7A, (byte)0x85, (byte)0x94, (byte)0x16, (byte)0x31, (byte)0x88 };


byte[] bCipherText = Base64.decode(CipherText);


Cipher oC3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
SecretKeySpec    oKey = new SecretKeySpec(s_desKeyData , "DESede");
IvParameterSpec oIvSpec = new IvParameterSpec(s_baIV);

oC3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, oKey, oIvSpec);
byte[] plaintext = oC3des.doFinal(bCipherText );

return new String(plainText, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Can you please add some content?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you writing your own certificate parser?

Comment: i have a servlet and to access that servlet i need to provide a access key as a request paramter(cipherText). The request parameter is validated in the servlet before proceeding. Am trying to access the servlet in the browser and provide the request paramter and value in url .